# Button with an X at the upper-right corner of the form, how to catch this event @ C#

Tags: c#, winforms, events

Which event is fired when I close a form  with the X button? 
I want the event that fires only when the X button is pressed; I know that there is a FormClosing event, but the problem is that it fires each time when form is closed... 
It also fires when `frm.close()` executes, and I don't want that to happen.

Answer (score 8):

There is no specific event wired up to the X in the upper right hand corner of the form.

Instead, use the form's [FormClosing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing(VS.80).aspx) event.  It has a Cancel parameter which you can set to `true` if you don't want the form to close.  This allows you to check for form closings that take place via other means, such as the OK button being clicked.

Comment: QueryUnload event is unheard of in WinForms.

Answer (score 8):

You can check the CloseReason property of FormClosingEventArgs parameter. It is CloseReason.UserClosing when you click the 'X' button.

Comment: exactly , the answer I want !

Answer (score 2):

As Robert stated there is no specific event associated with 'X', but you basically have two options which can be used to solve your probelm.

(i) **Form Closing** - This event occurs when you click the 'X', but before closing the form. So you can use this event handler to do some stuff just before closing the form. For example, you can stop the form from being closed / destroyed by using e.Cancel();

(ii) **Form Closed** - This event occurs when the form is closed.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I use the form's [OnClosing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onclosing.aspx) event, which can be cancelled as well.

Comment: Obsolete in .NET Framework 2.0 and later.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onclosing.aspx