# FormClosing not called when clicking Big Red X in the corner

Tags: c#, winforms, formclosing

I found this:

[Button with an X at the upper-right corner of the form, how to catch this event @ C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416099/button-with-an-x-at-the-upper-right-corner-of-the-form-how-to-catch-this-event)

Which says I should use the FormClosing event to find out when the window is closing because of a click on the X.

But my event code never gets called:

```
private void MainWin_FormClosing(Object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    m_closeThread = true;
    Application.Exit();
}
```

I must be missing something basic, but I don't know what.

Comment: Has the event been delegated to the handler?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must either subscribe to the event like:

```
this.FormClosing += this.MainWin_FormClosing;
```

in the form's constructor (or somewhere), or use:

```
override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    m_closeThread = true;
    Application.Exit();
}
```

Comment: Awesome, that did it. I assumed a Form would already be subscribed to this event when it was created.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you're correctly subscribing to the [FormClosing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx) event.

You must have on your MainWin dialog (tipically in the constructor), something like this:

```
this.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(MainWin_FormClosing);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Or the shorter version `this.FormClosing += MainWin_FormClosing;` :)